# Ionic native HTTP catch is null

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am playing around with Ionic and would like to make an API call to a REST API that I wrote in ASP .NET Core. Now I know the API works 100% as I am able to use Postman to call it and it works without issue.

However when I try to call the API from Ionic using the native http client I am getting a weird error. The catch of the promise is being triggered but there is no error. The code I am using is as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [HTTP]
})

export class HomePage {
  credentialsForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private http: HTTP) {

    this.credentialsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onLogin() {
    let endpoint = "https://api.mywebsite.mytld/api/vi/";

    var data = {
      "emailAddress": this.credentialsForm.controls['email'].value,
      "password": this.credentialsForm.controls['password'].value
    }

    this.http.post('https://api.mywebsite.mytld/api/vi/token', JSON.stringify(data), {headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}})
      .then(data => {
        console.log('Success');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Failure');
        console.log(error.status);
        console.log(error.error); // error message as string
        console.log(error.headers);

      });
  }

}
```

The output I am  getting in the console is the following:

```
[app-scripts] [12:57:50]  console.log: Failure
[app-scripts] [12:57:50]  console.log: null
[app-scripts] [12:57:50]  console.log: null
[app-scripts] [12:57:50]  console.log: null
```

Do you possibly have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: No need to stringify your data. Http module will work it out for you. Also on the catch, I'd rather log error itself rather then properties it does't have ;)

Comment: When debugging, what do you see in the network tab of developer tools?  That should tell you what's going on in the HTTP level.